# Real Analysis Cardinality Proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that given a finite set A and an uncountable set B, B and A union B have the same cardinality.

I looks to me like I need to show that there is are injective functions from B to A union B and from A union B to B.

The first injective function from B to A union B can just be the identity function but I am having trouble showing that there exists an injective function from A union B to B.

Any help showing this or ideas for other approaches to this problem would be greatly appreciated, 
Thanks!

Edit:
Yes, I am meant to show that B and A union B have the same cardinality.

Comment: $A$ and $A\cup B$ do not have the same cardinality. Did you mean $B$ and $A\cup B$?

Comment: Use the fact that an uncountably infinite set has a countably infinite subset (see a variety of proofs here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_has_Countably_Infinite_Subset). Then you can apply @copper.hat 's solution to set up a bijection involving the countably infinite subset. (with the remainder of the uncountable set bijecting to itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea: Suppose $Q=\{q_n\}$ is a countable collection of distinct elements,
and $R=\{r_1,...,r_k\}$ is a finite set of other (distinct) elements.

Define $\phi(r_i) = q_i$ and $\phi(q_i) = q_{i+k}$. Then $\phi: Q \cup R \to Q$ is a bijection.

That is, if we have a countable collection, we can 'absorb' a finite number of elements (in fact, we can 'absorb' a countable collection by interleaving the two collections).

Comment: The infinite set is defined as **un**countable

Comment: @TomCollinge: I understand, this was a hint...